# Absolute maximum and minimum points of $ y = x(x^2-1) $

Tags: calculus

how can I find absolute maximum and minimum points of $ y = x(x^2-1) $ ? I do not have any idea how to find absolute maximum and minimum points but I know the procedure of finding local maximum and minimum points .

Comment: Probably . But I do not understand which one should be applied here  .

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to\infty}y = \infty$ and that $\lim_{x\to-\infty} = -\infty$. Thus, no absolute max or min.

Comment: Are you trying to find absolute mins/maxes on some closed interval?

Comment: I just want to know your approach .Many many thanks  @ anorton .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

It seems like you were not given more details, so here are some hints.

- It is clear there is no global min or max over the reals as the function either increases or decreases as we approach $\pm \infty$.
- We want to look for a local min and max.
- Find the derivative of the function $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, set it equal to zero and find the two roots, that is, find the critical points.
- Test the two roots for a local min and max.

Comment: Just finished an "extrema" problem myself! +1